# What android icon app is this? Please advise

Tags: app-icons

not sure what this icon is but any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the icon of Google Sheet file. It is visible in Google Drive for Google Sheet files. Google Sheet is an alternative to Microsoft Excel.
[image]

Comment: you are awesome! thanks so much!

Comment: @LoR4106 I'm glad it helped 
Don't forget to mark it as correct answer ✔